# Getting a fact from group not specified in role in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

My ansible playbook has specified which group it's for. But the role that is specified, needs to get a specific variable from another group the host is in, because the apache setup is dependent on which location group the host is in.

How can the role `apache`, get the fact `var_location` from groups that are not added in the playbook?

Inventory:

```
all:
  hosts:
    location_a:
      vars:
        var_location: site_a
      hosts:
        foo.example.com:
    location_b:
      vars:
        var_location: site_b
      hosts:
        bar.example.com:
  webservers:
    hosts:
      foo.example.com:
      bar.example.com:
```

Playbook:

```
- hosts: webservers
  become: true
  roles:
     - apache
```

How is it possible to get that variable?

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: The format of inventory is wrong. The keyword "children" is missing. See [Inventory basics: formats, hosts, and groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#inventory-basics-formats-hosts-and-groups).

Comment: I'm not used to YAML inventory format and something looks really wrong in it for me, so i don't understand if `location_a` is a host or group. If it is a host, then you could try `hostvars["location_a"]["var_location"]`. If it is a group then you could move those vars from inventory file to seperate files like `group_vars/location_a` (it would be automatically loaded for group `location_a`) and then load it with `include_vars` task: `- include_vars: "{{ playbook_dir }}/group_vars/location_a"

Answer (score 0):

First, the inventory has a wrong format:

```
all:
  hosts:
    foo.example.com:
    bar.example.com:
  children:
    location_a:
      vars:
        var_location: site_a
      hosts:
        foo.example.com:
    location_b:
      vars:
        var_location: site_b
      hosts:
        bar.example.com:
    webservers:
      hosts:
        foo.example.com:
        bar.example.com:
```

And then you can see, that the group all contains all servers (use it to define hostvars). Then you have three children under all (group: location_a, location_b and webservers). foo is in webservers and location_a and bar is in webserver and location_b.

If you start now a role with all webservers, then the host is still part of the group location_a or location_b and you have still access to the vars var_location.